# How to get Kappa and MCC from nested cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn, cohens-kappa, nested-models

Let's take this well known [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html). How could I get the Kappa score and the Matthews correlation coefficient from nested cross-validation?

I've tried to make it with `cross_val_predict` instead of `cross_val_score`, but I found out that the results of the two are not the same, and since I already have results with `cross_val_score`, I think I'd prefer to continue using it.

These are the libraries I'm using:

```
from sklearn.metrics import matthews_corrcoef
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score
```

Comment: Take a look at https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html

You can use this to make a custom metric and then pass it to a CV object